# Adding a group count column to a PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dplyr

I am coming from R and the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) to PySpark due to its superior Spark handling, and I am struggling to map certain concepts from one context to the other.

In particular, suppose that I had a dataset like the following

```
x | y
--+--
a | 5
a | 8
a | 7
b | 1
```

and I wanted to add a column containing the number of rows for each `x` value, like so:

```
x | y | n
--+---+---
a | 5 | 3
a | 8 | 3
a | 7 | 3
b | 1 | 1
```

In dplyr, I would just say:

```r
import(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("...")
df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    ungroup()
```

and that would be that. I can do something almost as simple in PySpark if I'm looking to **summarize** by number of rows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.read.csv("...") \
    .groupBy(col("x")) \
    .count() \
    .show()
```

And I thought I understood that `withColumn` was equivalent to dplyr's `mutate`. However, when I do the following, PySpark tells me that `withColumn` is not defined for `groupBy` data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.read.csv("...") \
    .groupBy(col("x")) \
    .withColumn("n", count("x")) \
    .show()
```

In the short run, I can simply create a second dataframe containing the counts and join it to the original dataframe. However, it seems like this could become inefficient in the case of large tables. What is the canonical way to accomplish this?

Comment: Great answer by @pault. As the first sentence of his answer states: "you have to specify the aggregation before you can display the results".

I think the OP was trying to avoid the count(), thinking of it as an action.

a key theoretical point on count() is:
*   if count() is called on a DF directly, then it is an Action
*   but if count() is called after a groupby(), then the count() is applied on a groupedDataSet and not a DF and count() becomes a transformation not an action.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you do a `groupBy()`, you have to specify the aggregation before you can display the results. For example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('a', 5),
    ('a', 8),
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 1),
]
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["x", "y"])
df.groupBy('x').count().select('x', f.col('count').alias('n')).show()
#+---+---+
#|  x|  n|
#+---+---+
#|  b|  1|
#|  a|  3|
#+---+---+
```

Here I used `alias()` to rename the column. But this only returns one row per group. If you want all rows with the count appended, you can do this with a `Window`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('x')
df.select('x', 'y', f.count('x').over(w).alias('n')).sort('x', 'y').show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  x|  y|  n|
#+---+---+---+
#|  a|  5|  3|
#|  a|  7|  3|
#|  a|  8|  3|
#|  b|  1|  1|
#+---+---+---+
```

Or if you're more comfortable with SQL, you can register the dataframe as a temporary table and take advantage of `pyspark-sql` to do the same thing:

```python
df.registerTempTable('table')
sqlCtx.sql(
    'SELECT x, y, COUNT(x) OVER (PARTITION BY x) AS n FROM table ORDER BY x, y'
).show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  x|  y|  n|
#+---+---+---+
#|  a|  5|  3|
#|  a|  7|  3|
#|  a|  8|  3|
#|  b|  1|  1|
#+---+---+---+
```

Comment: how to append all `unused` columns in first method(returning one row per group)?

Answer (score 10):

as @pault appendix

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...

(df
.groupBy(F.col('x'))
.agg(F.count('x').alias('n'))
.show())

#+---+---+
#|  x|  n|
#+---+---+
#|  b|  1|
#|  a|  3|
#+---+---+
```

enjoy

Answer (score 9):

I found we can get even more close to the tidyverse example:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('x')
df.withColumn('n', f.count('x').over(w)).sort('x', 'y').show()
```