# How to select the corresponding value of another column when percentile_approx returns a single value of a particular column based on groupby?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark, need few clarifications.
I have a PySpark table something like this:

```
+---+-------+-----+-------+
| id| ranges|score|    uom|
+---+-------+-----+-------+
|  1|    low|   20|percent|
|  1|verylow|   10|percent|
|  1|   high|   70|  bytes|
|  1| medium|   40|percent|
|  1|   high|   60|percent|
|  1|verylow|   10|percent|
|  1|   high|   70|percent|
+---+-------+-----+-------+
```

I want to calculate percentile value of score column with given percentage as *0.95*, along with it I want that it should return the corresponding range value too. I tried running this query:

```
results = spark.sql('select percentile_approx(score,0.95) as score, first(ranges)  from subset GROUP BY id')
```

I get a result something like this:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|score|first(ranges, false)|
+-----+--------------------+
|   70|                 low|
+-----+--------------------+
```

It returns me the first value of ranges which is incorrect, it should be 'high'.
If I remove first(ranges) from my query it gives me error:

```
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"expression 'subset.`ranges`' is
> neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add
> to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care
> which value you get.;;\nAggregate [id#0L],
> [percentile_approx(score#2L, cast(0.95 as double), 10000, 0, 0) AS
> score#353L, ranges#1]\n+- SubqueryAlias subset\n   +- LogicalRDD
> [id#0L, ranges#1, score#2L, uom#3], false\n
```

Comment: You need to use a `Window` function - look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe/48793914#48793914).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are grouping by id only. So by using the first function you are effectively choosing a random value from the ranges column.

One solution would be to create a second dataframe that is contains the mapping of score to range, then joining that back into the results df at the end.

```
>>> df.registerTempTable("df") # Register first before selecting from 'df'
>>> map = spark.sql('select ranges, score from df')

>>> results = spark.sql('select percentile_approx(score,0.95) as score from subset GROUP BY id')

>>> results .registerTempTable("results ") 
>>> final_result = spark.sql('select r.score, m.ranges from results as r join map as m on r.score = m.score')
```