# Extract specific rows in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = [(("ID1", "A", 1)), (("ID1", "B", 5)), (("ID2", "A", 12)), 
       (("ID3", "A", 3)), (("ID3", "B", 3)), (("ID3", "C", 5)), (("ID4", "A", 10))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Type", "Value"])
df.show()

+---+----+-----+
| ID|Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID1|   A|    1|
|ID1|   B|    5|
|ID2|   A|   12|
|ID3|   A|    3|
|ID3|   B|    3|
|ID3|   C|    5|
|ID4|   A|   10|
+---+----+-----+
```

I want to extract only those rows (or IDs) which contain only one specific Type - "A"

Hence my expected output will contain following rows

```
+---+----+-----+
| ID|Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID2|   A|    1|
|ID4|   A|   10|
+---+----+-----+
```

For each ID can contain any Type - A,B,C etc. I want to extract those IDs which contain one and only one Type - 'A'

How can I achieve this in PySpark

Comment: Add a [group count column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe/48793914#48793914) and filter for where the count is equal to 1.

Comment: This should do -`from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, collect_list, array_contains, size, first` and then  `df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg(first(col('Type')).alias('Type'),first(col('Value')).alias('Value'),collect_list('Type').alias('Type_Arr'))`

Comment: `df = df.where(array_contains(col('Type_Arr'),'A') & (size(col('Type_Arr'))==1)).drop('Type_Arr')`

Comment: @cph_sto: Your answer is correct, can you please write this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @Hardikgupta Just did that, with slight modification so as to address the issue of multiple `A`s under one `ID`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by OP, I am jotting down the answer which I wrote under comments.

The aim of the problem at hand is to filter out the `DataFrame`where every particular `ID` is having just an element of `Type` `A` and none of the other.

```
# Loading the requisite packages
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_set, array_contains, size, first
```

The idea is to [`aggregate()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg) the `DataFrame` by `ID` first, whereby we group all `unique` elements of `Type` using [`collect_set()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) in an array. It's important to have `unique` elements, because it can happen that for a particular `ID` there could be two rows, with both of the rows having `Type` as `A`. That's why we should use [`collect_set()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) as opposed to [`collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) because the later won't return unique elements, but rather all the elements.

Then we should use [`first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) to get the first value of `Type` and `Value` in a group. In case `A` is the only `unique` `Type` possible for a particular `ID`, then the `first()` will return the only value of `A` in case `A` occurs once and the top value if there are duplicates of `A`.

```
df = df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg(first(col('Type')).alias('Type'),
                                 first(col('Value')).alias('Value'),
                                 collect_set('Type').alias('Type_Arr'))
df.show()
+---+----+-----+---------+
| ID|Type|Value| Type_Arr|
+---+----+-----+---------+
|ID2|   A|   12|      [A]|
|ID3|   A|    3|[A, B, C]|
|ID1|   A|    1|   [A, B]|
|ID4|   A|   10|      [A]|
+---+----+-----+---------+
```

Finally, we shall put 2 conditions simultaneously to filter out the required dataset.

*Condition 1:* It checks for the presence of `A` in the array of `Type` using [`array_contains()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains).

*Condition 2:* It checks for the [`size`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) of the array. In case the size is greater than 1, then there should be multiple `Types`.

```
df = df.where(array_contains(col('Type_Arr'),'A') & (size(col('Type_Arr'))==1)).drop('Type_Arr')
df.show()
+---+----+-----+
| ID|Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID2|   A|   12|
|ID4|   A|   10|
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: Clever use of first.

Answer (score 8):

You can apply a filter to it.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data = [(("ID1", "A", 1)), (("ID1", "B", 5)), (("ID2", "A", 12)), 
       (("ID3", "A", 3)), (("ID3", "B", 3)), (("ID3", "C", 5)), (("ID4", "A", 10))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Type", "Value"])
df.show()

+---+----+-----+
| ID|Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID1|   A|    1|
|ID1|   B|    5|
|ID2|   A|   12|
|ID3|   A|    3|
|ID3|   B|    3|
|ID3|   C|    5|
|ID4|   A|   10|
+---+----+-----+

x= df.filter(f.col('Type')=='A')

x.show()
```

If we need to filter all the IDs that have only one record and that too with Type as 'A' then below code may be the solution

```
df.registerTempTable('table1')


sqlContext.sql('select a.ID, a.Type,a.Value from table1 as a, (select ID, count(*) as cnt_val from table1 group by ID) b where a.ID = b.ID and (a.Type=="A" and b.cnt_val ==1)').show()


+---+----+-----+
| ID|Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID2|   A|   12|
|ID4|   A|   10|
+---+----+-----+
```

There will be better alternative ways to find the same.

Comment: I am getting an error `keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: x = df.filter(f.col('Type')=='A'). It should be two = symbol. Updated the answer.

Comment: My apologies, this is not what OP is asking. You are just filtering out the rows which have an `A` in them. Where as, OP is asking for those `IDs` which have only `A` in them `AND` none of the other alphabets.

Comment: @cph_sto, oh, yeah. Updated the answer. Thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 3):

I'm not fluent in Python, here a possible solution in Scala:

```
df.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_set("Type").as("Types"))
  .select("ID").where((size($"Types")===1).and(array_contains($"Types", "A"))).show()
+---+
| ID|
+---+
|ID2|
|ID4|
+---+
```

The idea is grouping by `ID` and filtering just the `Types` of size 1 containing `A` value.

Comment: Aggregation should be `collect_set` instead of `collect_list` just in case when ID ends up having multiple instances of `"A"`