# Understanding groupby, reduceByKey on transformed dataset

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am working with a large dataset on a standalone spark set up. I am still new to spark(so my fundamentals might be a little weak). Also I hope I don't fall for the XY trap...

The task is relatively simple in pandas but I can't seem to debug my pyspark error.

I have the following dataset.

```
+-------------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|           id|latitude| longitude| timestamp|        categoryname|
+-------------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|f69bfce8-a2c5|5.866167|118.088919|1551319828|                null|
|b9d48e00-0e57|3.224278| 101.72999|1551445560|   CONVENIENCE STORE|
|a6c5d9e2-1f99|3.148319| 101.61653|1551530554|         RESTAURANTS|
|92988985-67e2| 1.54056| 110.31867|1551458606|                null|
|e1771886-cb87|2.803712|101.663718|1551352028|                null|
```

Using a udf I was able to calculate the distance for each row from a single point using the haversine lib.

```
distance_udf = F.udf(lambda lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2: haversine((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)))
```

Giving me

```
+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------+------------------+
|           id|     categoryname|latitude| longitude|          distance|
+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------+------------------+
|f69bfce8-a2c5|             null|5.866167|118.088919|1846.2724187047768|
|b9d48e00-0e57|CONVENIENCE STORE|3.224278| 101.72999|10.727485447625341|
|a6c5d9e2-1f99|      RESTAURANTS|3.148319| 101.61653| 4.505927571918682|
|92988985-67e2|             null| 1.54056| 110.31867|  979.531392507226|
|e1771886-cb87|             null|2.803712|101.663718| 40.27783211167852|
+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------+------------------+
```

After `.filter()` and `.drop()` I am left with

```
+-------------+--------------------+
|           id|        categoryname|
+-------------+--------------------+
|d05e2151-0fb9|                null|
|8900e7dd-d51e|                null|
|a1e712f9-0784|RESIDENTIAL BUILDING|
|5b2c6eb3-f13e|                null|
|c7a05929-43fb|         RESTAURANTS|
+-------------+--------------------+
```

I have tried `df.groupby('categoryname').count()` on the transformed dataframe and get an error

I am trying to get the count of each categoryname.

I have also tried to convert it into `RDD` and tried using `.reduceByKey()` to no avail.

What am I missing? Is it my set up? the dataset isn't that big; only 50Gb.
The `groupby()` functions works fine when i first load the dataset but dosen't seem to work once I have done a few transformations.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Uni\DataBooks\Movingwalls\sparkTest.py", line 52, in <module>
    results = spark.sql('''SELECT count(DISTINCT idfa), categoryname FROM test2 GROUP BY categoryname''').show()
  File "C:\Users\Siddharth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\Users\Siddharth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\Siddharth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Siddharth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o110.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)

    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)

    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)

    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)

    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)

    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)


Driver stacktrace:

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)

    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)

    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)

    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)

    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)

    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)

    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)

    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)

    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
```

Comment: Your code works for me and I get the right count. What `error` are you getting by the way? You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: I found my error... some latitude and longitude were null.... I feel stupid

Comment: Please add the exact error you get. That will be great.

Comment: @JimTodd Added the error