# Getting count of grouped columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that contains 3 networks and each network has many stations. What I'd like to do is get the total number of stations for each network. The dataframe should still include the network and station name, so it should look like this:

```
Network Station Total
XMN     DIS     3     
XMN     CNN     3
XMN     JFK     3
ALK     DIS     2
ALK     CNN     2
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm assuming I would need to groupby the columns and then use a window function to partition by network and station to get the total number? I'm unsure, but how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a group count column to a PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe/48793914#48793914).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window.partitionBy` does exactly that:

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(Network='XMN', Station='DIS'),
    Row(Network='XMN', Station='CNN'),
    Row(Network='XMN', Station='JFK'),
    Row(Network='ALK', Station='DIS'),
    Row(Network='ALK', Station='CNN')
])

df.select("Network", "Station", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("Network")).alias("Total")).show()
```

Output:

```
.+-------+-------+-----+
|Network|Station|Total|
+-------+-------+-----+
|    XMN|    DIS|    3|
|    XMN|    CNN|    3|
|    XMN|    JFK|    3|
|    ALK|    DIS|    2|
|    ALK|    CNN|    2|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to groupBy, get the count and join back with your original dataframe

```
scala> val df = Seq(("XMN", "DIS"), ("XMN", "CNN"), ("XMN", "JFK"), ("ALK", "DIS"), ("ALK", "CNN")).toDF("Network", "Station")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Network: string, Station: string]

scala> df.show
+-------+-------+
|Network|Station|
+-------+-------+
|    XMN|    DIS|
|    XMN|    CNN|
|    XMN|    JFK|
|    ALK|    DIS|
|    ALK|    CNN|
+-------+-------+


scala> val grpCountDF = df.groupBy("Network").count
grpCountDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Network: string, count: bigint]

scala> grpCountDF.show
+-------+-----+
|Network|count|
+-------+-----+
|    XMN|    3|
|    ALK|    2|
+-------+-----+


scala> val outputDF = df.join(grpCountDF, "Network")
outputDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Network: string, Station: string ... 1 more field]

scala> outputDF.show
+-------+-------+-----+
|Network|Station|count|
+-------+-------+-----+
|    XMN|    DIS|    3|
|    XMN|    CNN|    3|
|    XMN|    JFK|    3|
|    ALK|    DIS|    2|
|    ALK|    CNN|    2|
+-------+-------+-----+
```