# Getting the Min value associated country

Tags: pyspark

I have a data set which contains country,region,value,product. Need to get min_x and region-country with min-value as sperate columns

### dataset

```
cust    Country Region  value   product
 100    france  europe   1       x
 101    france  europe   2       x
 102    poland  europe   3       x
 103    poland  europe   3       y
 104    france  europe   4       y
 105    france  europe   5       y
```

I want min value of the each product across all the customers. for this I had done group by prodcut.

```
cust    Country Region  value   product min_x
 100    france  europe  1   x   1
 101    france  europe  2   x   1
 102    poland  europe  3   x   1
 103    poland  europe  3   y   3
 104    france  europe  4   y   3
 105    france  europe  5   y   3



 df = spark.read.csv('dataset',header=True)
 df1 = df.groupBy('Product').agg(min(df.value).alias('min_x))
```

Need one more colum with region-country with min_value of x. when joining not able to get the values of country and region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a group count column to a PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: Same concept as the post I linked, but use `pyspark.sql.functions.min` instead of `pyspark.sql.functions.count` as the aggregate function.

Comment: @pault, Thanks for the reply but as I tried using window function to get min value but my issue is getting region-country of the min value product.

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution.

```
df = spark.read.csv(path,header=True)
w1 = Window.partitionBy(df.product).orderBy(df.value.desc())
df = df.withColumn('min_x',min(df.value).over(w1)).\
        withColumn('region_country',concat_ws('_',first('region'),first('country')))
```