# pyspark add min value to back to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to find the min date in a column 'dateclosed' in a pyspark dataframe.  I then want to add a column to my original dataframe, so that every record would have the minimum date 'Open_Date'.  This really seems like it shouldn't be that hard, but I keep getting errors.  I've also tried using "join" and creating a field with only one value in both dataframes and trying to join them on that, but again I just get errors.  Does anyone have a solution?

Code:

```
tst2_df=tst_df[['dateclosed']].agg({'dateclosed':'min'})\
.withColumnRenamed('min(dateclosed)','Open_Date')


tst_df.withColumn('Open_Date',lit(tst2_df[['Open_Date']].collect()[0])).show()
```

errors:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [2017-01-01]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1571940153295_0002/container_1571940153295_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 44, in _
    jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1571940153295_0002/container_1571940153295_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1571940153295_0002/container_1571940153295_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1571940153295_0002/container_1571940153295_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [2017-01-01]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update:

This hack worked, thanks for the tip Pault

```
tst_df2=tst_df.withColumn('BS',lit('a'))

w = Window.partitionBy('BS')

tst_df2.select('BS','dateclosed', min('dateclosed').over(w).alias('n')).show()
```

Comment: Use a `Window` - this is similar to [Adding a group count column to a PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe), except use `pyspark.sql.functions.min` as the aggregate function.

Comment: @pault thanks for getting back to me so soon.  I'm sorry I don't think I made it clear in my original post.  The value should be the same for all records.  it would be the min dateclosed in the entire column.  I'm not clear on how to get that with a window function, won't it just give me the minimum for the value I'm partitioning by?

Comment: @pault thanks, I got it with your tip.

Comment: No problem, but it's better to either delete the question or add your solution as an answer. Don't add it to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
tst_df2=tst_df.withColumn('BS',lit('a'))

w = Window.partitionBy('BS')

tst_df2.select('BS','dateclosed', min('dateclosed').over(w).alias('n')).show()
```