# Pyspark - Add column with number of occurences

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column A and I would like to aggregate another column with the occurence of the distinct values in A without resulting in a grouped dataframe, I mean I would like to have the following:

| A | A_counts |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 2 |
| a | 3 |

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: use the `count` window function with an arbitrary partition col. see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672901/get-total-row-count-over-a-window)

Comment: `groupBy` + `count` then join with the original dataframe  with `A` as key

Comment: @philantrovert 's answer solved my problem!
`df.join(df.groupBy("A").count(), ["A"], 'left').withColumnRenamed("count","A_counts")`
Thank you very much!!