# Pyspark: Add column with average of groupby

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 0, 100), 
        (2, 0, 200),
        (3, 1, 150), 
        (4, 1, 250),
    ],
    ['id', 'flag', 'col1'] 
)
```

I would like to create another column and input the average of the groupby of the flag

```
test.groupBy(f.col('flag')).agg(f.avg(f.col("col1"))).show()

+----+---------+
|flag|avg(col1)|
+----+---------+
|   0|    150.0|
|   1|    200.0|
+----+---------+
```

End product:

```
+---+----+----+---+
| id|flag|col1|avg|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   0| 100|150|
|  2|   0| 200|150|
|  3|   1| 150|200|
|  4|   1| 250|200|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a group count column to a PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: You can join the grouped dataframe back to the original dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `window` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('flag')
test.withColumn("avg", F.avg("col1").over(w)).show()

+---+----+----+-----+                                                           
| id|flag|col1|  avg|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  1|   0| 100|150.0|
|  2|   0| 200|150.0|
|  3|   1| 150|200.0|
|  4|   1| 250|200.0|
+---+----+----+-----+
```