# Group by plus count() not working correctly

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I am working with a dataframe on pyspark and i am trying to add a new column that contains the count of distinct records as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793701/adding-a-group-count-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe). This is the code i am using:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df= df.groupBy('CUSTOMER').count().select('CUSTOMER', func.col('count').alias('COUNT'))
```

It works properly for about 180k records but there are a few records in which i am getting something like this:

| CUSTOMER | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 50 |
| 123456 | 50 |

Instead of something like this, which is what i expect:

| CUSTOMER | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 100 |

I noticed that the data type of `CUSTOMER` on hive (as the data frame is written into a database later) is `decimal(12,0)` so i thought that maybe some records had `CUSTOMER = 123456` and other ones `CUSTOMER=123456.0` and somehow that was different so i went and modified the query that creates the data frame (from another hive database) to use `CAST(CUSTOMER AS INT) AS CUSTOMER` on the select statement but i still get the same result.

Any ideas on what else could be causing this issue or what else i can check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `df.printSchema()` show?

Comment: also can you share your queries and maybe sample data

Comment: Use `F.trim("CUSTOMER")`. E.g. `df = df.groupBy(F.trim("CUSTOMER")).agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('COUNT'))`